# PRG variant as a commitment scheme

Tags: random-number-generator, reference-request, pseudo-random-generator, commitments

I would like to use a PRG in order to achieve the commitment properties (i.e. Hiding and Binding), however, if we look at a general PRG we cannot state that it has the Binding property.

First I show that it could be shown that it has the Hiding property: given the PRG result on a random seed $s$, i.e. given $g=PRG(s)$, the receiver cannot tell the pre-image of $g$ with more than negligible probability since if there exist a receiver that can produce the pre-image than we can construct a distinguisher to the PRG with the same probability of success.

On the other hand, if we look at the binding property, we cannot state the above, since there exist PRGs that output the same result when operating on seed $s$ and when operating on seed $s+1$ for every even $s$. This can be easily proven. (And thus, the sender surely can commit on even $s$ and later open $s+1$).

My question: Does there exist a variant of a PRG that is proven to provide the commitment properties?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme#Bit-commitment_from_a_pseudo-random_generator $\;$

Comment: Thanks for the reference, this is too theoretically though. I'm looking for more practical/simple/efficient use of PRG, I mean that that the protocol is non-interactive - the only message is from the sender (committer) to the receiver , and the committed value is a bit-string rather than one bit.

Comment: There does not "exist a variant of a PRG that is proven to provide the commitment properties", since $\hspace{.13 in}$ there does not exist _any_ plain-model protocol "that is proven to provide the commitment properties". $\hspace{.32 in}$

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you last comment, by "plain model" you mean that there does not exist a proven commitment scheme that is not relying on some assumption? (like one-way-function)

Comment: By "plain model", I mean without stuff like [sufficiently-fair noisy channels](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Publication/691366/unfair-noisy-channels-and-oblivious-transfer), [physical unclonable functions](http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2013/papers/4977a286.pdf), [tamper-evident seals](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11523468_24), or [assuming that there's sufficient noise in the receiver's quantum storage](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v3/n12/full/ncomms2268.html). $\hspace{.55 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer are there really no commitment schemes in the plain model? How about, e.g, Pedersen commitments?

Comment: @GuutBoy : $\;\;\;$ There are really no "schemes in the plain model" that are "proven to provide the commitment properties". $\:$ In particular, if a scheme provides the commitment properties then it is secure, the theorem on [page 10 of this paper](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/techreports/tr-89-31.pdf#page=12) says that "Any secure bit commitment protocol can be used to construct a distributionally one-way function.", $\:$ (continued ...) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (... continued) $\:$ [Lemma 1](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/techreports/tr-89-31.pdf#page=8) on page 6 of that paper says "If there is a distribution ally one-way function then there is a one-way function.", and by amplification and the search-to-decision reduction, if there is a one-way function then [$\: \operatorname{RP} \neq \operatorname{NP} \;$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP_(complexity))$\;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer sure, we must a assume one-way functions but does that mean we are no longer in the plain model? I guess I am a little confused about what people mean by the plain model.

Comment: @GuutBoy : $\;\;\;$ That does not "mean we are no longer in the plain model". $\:$ The "plain model" means that all computational limitations are soft (in particular, can't use [timed commitments](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=704125) or the [bounded storage model](http://www.crypto.wpi.edu/Publications/Documents/bounded_icn.pdf)), the adversary's only limitations on working with qubits are computational and physical (so no [noisy-storage model](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v3/n12/full/ncomms2268.html)), $\:$ (continued ...) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (... continued) $\:$ there are no trusted parties and no [trusted strings](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~rafail/PUBLIC/85.pdf), the parties are limited to sending bits and qubits to each other (as opposed to, for example, sending tamper-evident seals or physical uncloneable functions or other hardware), and clocks are inaccurate (generally, they can only be used to detect that absence of an expected message). $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: In [this paper](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rafael/papers/ccacommit.pdf) they informally define the *plain model* as one that provides only authenticated communication channels. Also they show a commitment protocol in that model. I'm not expert in commitments nor in the plain model and probably the argument you mentioned above is more general. Back to my question, I'm interesting in an *efficient* commitment scheme even if it relies on one-way-function, by efficient I mean that it is non-interactive and can treat an entire bit-string at once with low-cost (like a PRG/PRF).